# Как при смене Views через TabBar не стирать предыдущий View

Tags: objective-c

У всех `Views Background Color = Clear Color` и `Clears Graphic Contents` выключены.

Перед прорисовкой нового View экран раньше становился черным.

После вставки кода:

```
(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 
self.view.clearsContextBeforeDrawing=NO;
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

стал закрашиваться в красный, но если ставлю `ClearColor`, все равно черный.

Comment: закрасил     self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]. Теперь во время отрисовки цвет фона - зеленый. Таким образом перед прорисовкой контекста стирается нарисованный до этого контекст. Как сделать так, чтобы этот контекст не стирался?

Comment: решил сделать snapshot предыдущего вида и всунуть его в новый вид. Частично решило проблему - но происходит короткое моргание перед этим. Т.е. содержимое стирается и снова отрисовывается.